# Show Alert_Dialog in bottom of view

Tags: dart, flutter, dialog, android-alertdialog

I Have an Alert dialog menu which contain a grid view containing some button, I need my Alert dialog to be shown on bottom of page not in the middle. My question is how to do it.

```
  Widget _buildAboutDialog(BuildContext context)  {
    return new AlertDialog(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,

  content: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
    child: new GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 4,
        children: new List<Widget>.generate(8, (index) {
              return new GridTile(
                  child: new Card(
                  color: Colors.blue.shade200,
                  child: new Center(
                  child: new Text('$index'),
                    )
                  )
              );
                })),
      ) ],
  ),),
);


  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you shouldn't use the alert dialog and instead show a dialog with your own widget.

Do note that i'm a bit puzzled if you need a dialog at all. If you don't need a dialog attached is some methods that may hopefully help.

If you just need a widget:

```
Widget bottomGridTiles(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
      GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true, // Important
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          children: List<Widget>.generate(8, (index) {
            return GridTile(
                child: Card(
                    color: Colors.blue.shade200,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('$index'),
                    )));
          }))
    ],
  );
}
```

If you need a dialog with the widget:

```
void _buildDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return bottomGridTiles(context);
      });
}
```

Widget that opens the dialog:

```
Widget openDialogButton(BuildContext context) {
  return RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () => _buildDialog,
    child: Text("Open Dialog"),
  );
}
```

Comment: You can try to set the GridView's childAspectRatio parameter to change the shape of the buttons ex:
childAspectRatio: 3/2. 

You can also set the widget's padding field if you want some spacing between the widget and the screen edges:
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),